# VPN Network and Kubernetes Clusters

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, kubernetes

I have a question regarding a best practice when it comes to setting up a kubernetes cluster with VMs across multiple, physical servers. We were able to successfully setup a cluster between multiple VM instances on one single, physical server. One of these VM instances is the master node. The VM instances do not have a unique public IP of their own, only internal IP.

Eventually this single server will run out of resources. The idea is to just setup an additional server with again multiple VM instances on it, and join those new VM instances as new nodes to the existing cluster.

- Does something like this work ?
- Do all VM instances have to be in the same network ?
- Would that work with VPN ?
- Does this need another master node for each physical server ?

Thanks for any pointers and suggestions !

Comment: Hello. Creating Kubernetes cluster on multiple `VM`'s should work considering all of the requirements are met. As a pointer you could look on this official documentation about [creating highly available clusters with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/). Talking about the VPN are you trying to connect nodes/masters between sites or it serves a different purpose?  You could also look on this SF answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/1035490/can-kubernetes-cluster-nodes-be-geologically-spread-out/1036447#1036447

Comment: So creating the cluster on multiple VM's is not a Problem. We already have that. They're all connected through a private network, but all are running on one and the same physical server, so that's cool. But what about additional VM's which run on a different server ? Do they have to be in the same private network as well ? Or do you just create a master node on each server and join only the master nodes together ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this answer as community wiki as the question portrayed could be wide and not get the definitive answer.

Feel free to expand it.

---

As for:

> Does something like this work ?

Yes. In fact there are multiple ways to configure your cluster. I encourage you to visit sites below for an overview of Kubernetes components and architecture:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Overview: Components](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/)*

You can use below link (with a guide) to setup a cluster that will use the minimum of 3 masters and 3 workers nodes for highly available setup:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Setup: Production environment: Tools: Kubeadm: High availability](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/)*

> Some tips!
>
> - For production environments, you would need a dedicated HAProxy load balancer node (physical, virtual)
> - While master components can run on any machine, best practice dictates using a separate server for the master and not running any user containers on this machine.
> - It is best practice to run your clusters in a multi-master fashion in Production – to ensure high availability and resiliency of the master components themselves. This means you’ll need at least 3 Master nodes (an odd number, to ensure quorum

> As for quorum in `etcd`!
>
> Please remember that `etcd` requires a quorum to be operational. You can read more about it by following below link:
>
> - *[Github.com: Etcd-io: Documentation: FAQ: Why an odd number of cluster members](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/faq.md#why-an-odd-number-of-cluster-members)*

---

> Do all VM instances have to be in the same network ?

It will depend on the networking architecture of your setup. The easiest solution would be to create a private network that would span across multiple physical machines that you intend to deploy Kubernetes (to have nodes in the same network).

Paraphrasing what was just said:

- `VM #1` on `Physical server #1` could easily communicate with `VM #2` on `Physical server #2`

---

> Would that work with VPN ?

Please specify what exactly you mean by a VPN connection:

- Is it the connection between nodes in your network?
- Is it the connection that will connect the nodes between themselves from an offsite location?
- Is it a connection for developers/sysadmins to get access to your Kubernetes cluster?

As for a side note you can look on Wireguard (network plugin with built-in encryption):

- *[Gravitational.com: Blog: Announcing Wormhole](https://gravitational.com/blog/announcing-wormhole/)*

---

> Does this need another master node for each physical server ?

In short no **but**. There is always a but:

- You **can** create a cluster where there will be single master node  and multiple workers on multiple physical machines. This setup will work but it won't be highly available solution.
- You **can** create a cluster where there will be multiple master nodes span across multiple physical servers. This heavily depends on what exact needs you have.

I thought about this question and it could be a long shot but if you think that master and worker on each physical machine are coupled in any term, they aren't. Each worker should be able to communicate with each master node and vice versa.

---

> Do they have to be in the same private network as well ? Or do you just create a master node on each server and join only the master nodes together ?

You need to run `$ kubeadm init` to initialize the cluster on a single master node. Then you will need to run  `$ kubeadm join` on each of the nodes (master/worker). The difference between them (master/worker) is the parameter:

- `--control-plane` # <-- this parameter will indicate a master node (use it only on a master node).

---

I also encourage you to check additional resources:

- *[Platform9.com: Blog: Kubernetes on premises why and how](https://platform9.com/blog/kubernetes-on-premises-why-and-how/)*
- *[Serverfault.com: Questions: Can kubernetes cluster nodes be geologically spread out?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035490/can-kubernetes-cluster-nodes-be-geologically-spread-out/1036447#1036447)*
- *[Github.com: Kelsey Hightower: Kubernetes the hard way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way)*